# Ruby cross-platform way to write the EOF symbol

Tags: ruby, string, cross-platform, eof

Is there a platform-independent way of writing the `EOF` symbol to a string in Ruby. In *nix I believe the symbol is `^D`, but in Windows is `^Z`, that's why I ask.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: e.g. I have some PDF files which could not me converted with "convert" (ImageMagick) because they are missing EOF marker. At the same time those files could be viewed by a desktop application. I would like to try adding such a marker and after that converting the PDFs...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EOF is not a character, it's a state. Terminals use control characters to represent this state (C-d). There's no such thing is "reading a EOF *character*" and same thing for writing one. If you're writing to a file, just close it when you're done. See this [mailing list post](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/248837):

> It sounds like you are thinking of EOF
>   as an in-band but special character
>   value that marks the end of file.  It
>   is better to think of it as an
>   out-of-band sentinel value.  In C, EOF
>   is usually -1 and the associated API
>   specifies integer return values so
>   that EOF is guaranteed to never be
>   confused with a valid in-band value.

Here's some more proof (do this on Unix):

```
$ cat > file
hello^V^Dworld
^D
$ cat file
helloworld
```

Typing ^V^D inserts a control-D character literally into the file. After typing world and enter, the ^D closes the pipe. The file ends up being 12 bytes long 10 letters, two more for the ^D and the newline. The final ^D does not end up in the file. It's just used by the terminal/shell to close the pipe.

Comment: it's a very common misconception that EOF is a character

Answer (score 6):

In general there is no EOF character.  That is, there's no cross-platform solution to this and even on specific platforms the handling of such a character is purely legacy and inconsistent.  You end a file by closing it.

However, to be pedantic, certain operating systems when reading files in certain modes do support a literal end of file character.  For example, if you're running under Windows and use the C stdio API to read a file in text mode then a literal control-Z (character code 26) will signal end of file to stdio.  This is a holdover from MS-DOS which it has as a holdover from CP/M.  If you use stdio and read the file in binary mode then the control-Z will not end the file.

Nevertheless, you should only think of it as "know, don't use" feature.  You'll want to know about it if you ever see trucated input/output on Windows, but using it is madness.